# The primitive type int of System does not have a field out

Tags: java

When I take

```
int System = 90;
System.out.println(System);
```

It is giving an error:"The primitive type int of System does not have a field out" in the println statement while declaration of int System is showing right.

Comment: Well ... what do you expect?  You have just declared `System` to be an `int`!!   Then you try to access a field of `System`.  Primitive types don't have fields.  This is the sort of stuff you will get if you disregard Java style guidelines.  A variable should **never** start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

The variable name "System" is shadowing the class "System".
You should use fully-qualified name of the class `System`, e.g:

```
int System = 90;
java.lang.System.out.println(System);
```

But it's better to follow Java naming convention and start the name of variable from a small letter

Answer (score 1):

System is a class name used in the same context, so you either use fully qualified name for the class usage [`java.lang.System`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) or you simply rename your variable(I would prefer this, helps understanding [code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)) :

```
int system = 90; // rename this 
System.out.println(system);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should never use **language reserved keywords** as variable names.
2. I suggest you read [Java Naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)